# How to make delay vibration when phone is ringing?

Tags: ringtone, vibration

How to make it start playing ringtone before it starts to vibrate?

I like when the phone starts ringing very gently at first (to prevent startling me or annoying others), and but gradually comes to full volume ringing after 20-30 seconds (to reach me from other room/covered/etc.).

But the vibrating itself is louder than the beginning of my ringtone and breaks that "gentle beginning" scheme. Tunring it off also not an option because of it is often the sole mean to discover the call.

Even better if I can configure myself the exact pattern of vibration, so that it is synced with the music.